# Como usar os eventos do mouse para criar efeito enter/out sem que os alementos dentro do elemento selecionado interfira

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-eventos, eventos-do-mouse

Queria que a div com class *block* ficasse com um contorno quando eu entrasse com o mouse dentro da div e depois a borda sumisse quando eu tirar o mouse.

Problema, quando eu passo o mouse por cima do h1 dentro da div.block a borda some, gostaria que o contorno permanecesse enquanto o mouse estiver dentro da div mesmo que por cima de outros elementos e depois sumisse apenas quando eu tirar o mouse da div

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

blocks.forEach(element =>
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
    event.target.style.border = '1px solid #666'
  }))
blocks.forEach(element =>
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
    event.target.style.border = '0'
  }))
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Douglas Takiuti</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente um texto fictício da indústria de impressão e composição. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto fictício padrão da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma galé do tipo e embaralhou para fazer um livro
    de amostra de tipos.</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h1>Douglas Takiuti</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente um texto fictício da indústria de impressão e composição. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto fictício padrão da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma galé do tipo e embaralhou para fazer um livro
    de amostra de tipos.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara troque o evento de `mouseenter` para `mouseover` e troque `.target` para `.currentTarget` e vai funcionar como o esperado ;)

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

blocks.forEach(element =>
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.style.border = '1px solid #666'
  }))
blocks.forEach(element =>
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.style.border = '0'
  }))
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Douglas Takiuti</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente um texto fictício da indústria de impressão e composição. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto fictício padrão da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma galé do tipo e embaralhou para fazer um livro
    de amostra de tipos.</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h1>Douglas Takiuti</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente um texto fictício da indústria de impressão e composição. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto fictício padrão da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma galé do tipo e embaralhou para fazer um livro
    de amostra de tipos.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se não quiser usar javascript é possível fazer usando apenas CSS.

Uma [pseudo-classe *CSS*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) é apenas uma palavra-chave adicionada a seletores *CSS* que especifica um estado especial do elemento selecionado.

Use a pseudo-classe *CSS* [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) que corresponde quando o usuário interage com um elemento usando um dispositivo apontador. Simplificando, `:hover` dispara quando o usuário passa o ponteiro do mouse sobre esse elemento.

No seu caso apenas descreva o estilo que deseja usar, `border: 1px solid #666;`, quando o usuário passar o mouse sobre um elemento *HTML* da classe `block`. Para isso crie um seletor *CSS* `.block` e adicione a pseudo-classe *CSS*`:hover`.

```css
.block:hover {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h1>Douglas Takiuti</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente um texto fictício da indústria de impressão e composição. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto fictício padrão da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma galé do tipo e embaralhou para fazer um livro
    de amostra de tipos.</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h1>Douglas Takiuti</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente um texto fictício da indústria de impressão e composição. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto fictício padrão da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma galé do tipo e embaralhou para fazer um livro
    de amostra de tipos.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma propriedade do css para isso, a proprieade :hover

No caso o seu código ficaria assim:

```
.block:hover{
    border:1px solid #666;
}
```